# Dynamic Thread Priority For All Threads Of An ExecutorService

Tags: java, spring, threadpoolexecutor

I have a couple of `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` in my Spring application. Based on some condition, I want the threads for 1 Executor to run at a different priority. For example during the day, background tasks are at a lower priority while servicing user requests. I see the `Thread` class has the `setPriority()` method which is my hook. The `ThreadFactory` also has the `setPriority()` method for creating new threads. The `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is a convenience wrapper around the jdk `ThreadPoolExecutor` which handles the thread pooling.

So I am looking for a way to perform a thread priority change by changing the `ThreadFactory` (in case new threads are created) and to change priority of all existing `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` threads. I could wrapper each Thread created by the factory and check is still valid but was looking for a better solution. Or is it as simple at setting the background tasks at lower priority and the java scheduler will run them at same speed if no other processing is performed?

Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: Just set a `ThreadFactory` on the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` which has the logic to determine the `priority` based on the conditions you want.

Comment: except it does not impact threads already created and in the thread pool

Comment: That is true, but if you set a TTL on your threads, they will eventually get the correct priority. Combined with a min/max on the pool and dynamic sizing it should yield the effect you want. Unless the queue is never empty and it is processing a huge number of tasks... However changing the priority of a thread might lead to errors/exception when the thread is busy (might depend on the platform and jvm being used).